# Flutter: Gsheets. Is there any way to pull values without keys?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this function to pull key, latitude, and longitude:

```
Map<double, double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2)).map(
    (key, value) => MapEntry(
        double.parse(key), value == null ? null : double.tryParse(value)));
List longitudelist = m2.values.where((value) => value != null).toList();
```

Latitude is of course pulled with the same, just with columns 2 from row 2.
Column 1 is numebered. one through how ever many points I have...

Is there any way I can simply pull latitude and longitude values and completely ignore keys? I want to be able to have latitude in column 1, longitude in 2, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Sure try to use ForEach( (e) { return Your_Funcation ; }

Check this for more :

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html

Comment: this wouldn't work i believe. i'd still be pulling the key..

Comment: I haven't created it. Judging by this: https://gist.github.com/aruld/1299218 I'd have to use forEach after i query the key and value together from Google sheets. I don't know if there's a way to use it to query value alone.